# Universal iPhone Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I decided to make an iPhone-only application but since there are so many different sizes of an iPhone screen I have no choice but use Auto-Layouts. There is a grid which allows you to chose width and height of the layout so I decided to choose the "wCompact hRegular" one because it says "Any iPhone in Portrait" but every time that I run my application on iPhone 6 it uses the "wCompact hAny" layout which does not work right. So my questions are:

- Is there any way to use ONLY wCompact hRegular layout?
- Is there a way to not use Size Classes and just stretch 16:9 iPhone 5
  version?
- And if there is not, what is the best solution for my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you not just design in wCompact hAny to cover any Compact width layouts?

Comment: If your app is iPhone-only, why do you even need size classes?

Answer (score 0):

Better you disable "Size Classes" and use "Auto Layout" instead. To do that 1. Select your storyboard file from your project navigator
2. In the file inspector under interface Builder Document check "Use Auto Layout".[image]